# Generating UML with Eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

Are there any plugin that allow me to generate uml diagrams with java source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good free UML tool for Java/Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse)

Comment: It seem he/she has the same requirement as mine.